# How should I implement the C# server side portion of long-polling for ajax requests?

Tags: c#, ajax, long-polling, waithandle, event-wait-handle

I've got an architecture that involves browsers polling via ajax every 3 seconds for updates and I'd like to change that to [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling).

I'd like to have 1, 2.. {n} clients long-polling, waiting for updates and have something happen on the server to signal the waiting clients to return.  My first thought was to use an [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx), and I can do this easily if I just want to support 1 client.  I'd just have an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) `WaitHandle` that would [`WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) to block the client, maybe with a timeout, maybe not.  Either way, an `AutoResetEvent` will only allow me to support 1 client (since it only wakes 1 waiting thread) and I want n clients.

I'm pretty sure I need to use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) `WaitHandle`, but I'm not sure when to call [`Reset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.reset.aspx) after I `Set` it (when waking the threads).  Should I simply [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(VS.71).aspx) some arbitrary amount in between the [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) and `Reset`?

In psuedo code, the waking logic would be

- get `ManualResetEventWaitHandle`
- call `Set`
- ensure all waiting clients have woken, while preventing new requests from blowing through
- call `Reset` now that all waiting clients have received their updates

Its that 3rd line that i'm having a hard time with.  Currently I am tossing around the idea of having a `LastTxID` that the client / server maintain and potentially using 2 wait handles.  However, before I went crazy with this implementation I wanted to get feedback here to see how they would implement the waking logic.

Edit: assume I've got the problems associated with having max concurrent users figured out, either by tweaking IIS or hosting via WCF or some other solution.  I only want to focus on the waking logic.

Comment: Check this out for a working implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446486.aspx

Comment: Please note that this is out of date and SignalR should be used for this sort of work now

Answer (score 0):

One idea, in pseudo code

- Maintain a thread-safe list of connection id's, possibly use the session id
- Give every connection its own AutoResetEventWaitHandle
- In a thread safe manner, loop through those wait handles and set them when there is an update
- on session end, in a thread safe manner, remove that connection / session id from the list

I'd love to get some feedback on this

con's to this approach

- have to maintain a list of connections
- have to generate {n} wait handles for {n} clients